# Is it possible to do Augmented Faces on iOS with ARCore?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

Does anyone know is it possible to do augmented faces on iOS with ARCore? I'm talking about this specifically:

https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity/augmented-faces/developer-guide

I know ARCore supports Cloud Anchor for iOS, I tried to paste 'ARkit device' from this sample project to Augmented Faces (replacing some components too) with no success. Do you know is it even possible? 
Please help!

Comment: Is there any update regarding this ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible!

Here's a quote from the [Augmented Faces iOS Developer Guide](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/ios/augmented-faces/developer-guide):

> 1. Clone or download the [ARCore SDK for iOS](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-ios-sdk/releases) from GitHub to obtain the
>      sample app code.
> 2. Open a Terminal window and run pod install from the
>      folder where the Xcode project exists.
> 3. Open the sample app in Xcode
>      version 10.3 or greater and connect the device to your development
>      machine via USB. To avoid build errors, make sure you are building
>      from the .xcworkspace file and not the .xcodeproj file.
> 4. Press Cmd+R or
>      click Run.  Use a physical device, not the simulator, to work with
>      Augmented Faces.
> 5. Tap “OK” to give the camera access to the sample app.
>      The app should open the front camera and immediately track your face
>      in the camera feed. It should place images of fox ears over both sides
>      of your forehead, and place a fox nose over your own nose.

You can also watch a video tutorial [here](https://youtu.be/QAqOTaCCD9M).

Answer (score 0):

No, at the moment of the writing, Aug 26, 2019, there is still no sign of an iOS release with augmented face support from Google's ARCore team.

For the iOS platform, the best bet is still Apple's ARKit with face tracking support, though limited to devices which supports the TrueDepth camera system.